# DialogFragment argument and nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

My class should pass an argument to DialogFragment, but my app crashes inside onCreate method (of dialog class) for a NullPointerException.
Dialog fragment class portion of code:

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment {

public ConfirmDialog() {}

 ConfirmDialog newInstance(String f) {
    ConfirmDialog d = new ConfirmDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("FILE_NAME", f);
    d.setArguments(args);

    return d;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    file = getArguments().getString("FILE_NAME");
}
```

I have the nullpointer at this line:

```
file = getArguments().getString("FILE_NAME");
```

And i don't know why.
I paste also the code calls the dialog

```
private void showConfirmDialog(String file) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog();
    Log.i("SHOWFILEACTIVITY", file);
    dialog.newInstance(file);
    dialog.show(fm, "fragment_confirm_dialog");
}
```

Here the "file" string is not null, i've check it with

```
Log.i("SHOWFILEACTIVITY", file);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a `ConfirmDialog` via the constructor, then calling `newInstance()`, which creates another (proper) `ConfirmDialog`. However you then discard that proper instance.

To fix this:

Your `newInstance()` method should be static:

```
public static ConfirmDialog newInstance(String f) {
    ConfirmDialog d = new ConfirmDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("FILE_NAME", f);
    d.setArguments(args);

    return d;
}
```

And `showConfirmDialog()` should be changed so it uses the `newInstance()` method properly.

```
private void showConfirmDialog(String file) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Log.i("SHOWFILEACTIVITY", file);

    ConfirmDialog dialog = ConfirmDialog.newInstance(file);
    dialog.show(fm, "fragment_confirm_dialog");
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, it works. I've never used newInstance function and i've made a mistake!
but why newInstance should be static?

Comment: @giozh since we want to create a `new` instance of the Dialog, it's a bad design approach to rely on an *already created* instance of the Dialog. Keeping the method static removes dependencies and results in less object creation.